# Encrypting properties before saving class to xml file

Tags: c#, encryption, xmlserializer

I am attempting to save a few pieces of the connection string as encrypted text to an XML from my class.

Here is my class:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using TechGuyComputing.CompleteOrganizerWPF.Data;

namespace TechGuyComputing.CompleteOrganizerWPF.MiscClasses
{
  public class AppSetting
  {
    private string _dataSource;
    private string _intitialCatalog;
    private string _userId;
    private string _password;

    public string DataSource
    {
      set => _dataSource = Encryption.SimpleEncryptWithPassword(value, GlobalConstants.EncryptionPassword);
      get => Encryption.SimpleDecryptWithPassword(_dataSource, GlobalConstants.EncryptionPassword);
    }

    public string IntitialCatalog
    {
      set => _intitialCatalog = Encryption.SimpleEncryptWithPassword(value, GlobalConstants.EncryptionPassword);
      get => Encryption.SimpleDecryptWithPassword(_intitialCatalog, GlobalConstants.EncryptionPassword);
    }

    public string UserId
    {
      set => _userId = Encryption.SimpleEncryptWithPassword(value, GlobalConstants.EncryptionPassword);
      get => Encryption.SimpleDecryptWithPassword(_userId, GlobalConstants.EncryptionPassword);
    }

    public string Password
    {
      set => _password = Encryption.SimpleEncryptWithPassword(value, GlobalConstants.EncryptionPassword);
      get => Encryption.SimpleDecryptWithPassword(_password, GlobalConstants.EncryptionPassword);
    }

    public bool IntegratedSecurity { set; get; }
    public bool MultipleActiveResultSets { set; get; }
    public bool PersistSecurityInfo { set; get; }
  }

  internal static class AppSettings
  {
    public static AppSetting ApplicationSettings;

    public static SqlConnection ConnectionString { get; private set; }


    static AppSettings()
    {
      if (ApplicationSettings == null)
      {
        ApplicationSettings = XmlReader.GetAppSettingsFromXmlFile();
        SetConnectionString();
      }
    }

    public static void SaveAppSettings()
    {
      if (ApplicationSettings == null)
      {
        ApplicationSettings = new AppSetting();
      }
      XmlReader.WriteAppSettingsToXmlFile(ApplicationSettings);
      SetConnectionString();
    }

    private static void SetConnectionString()
    {
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ApplicationSettings.DataSource) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(ApplicationSettings.IntitialCatalog))
      {
        ConnectionString = new SqlConnection();
        return;
      }

      var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
      {
        DataSource = ApplicationSettings.DataSource,
        InitialCatalog = ApplicationSettings.IntitialCatalog,
        IntegratedSecurity = ApplicationSettings.IntegratedSecurity,
        MultipleActiveResultSets = ApplicationSettings.MultipleActiveResultSets,
        PersistSecurityInfo = ApplicationSettings.PersistSecurityInfo,
        UserID = ApplicationSettings.UserId,
        Password = ApplicationSettings.Password
      };

      ConnectionString = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString);
    }

  }
}
```

And this is how I am saving the XML file:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace TechGuyComputing.CompleteOrganizerWPF.MiscClasses
{
  internal static class XmlReader
  {

    public static void WriteAppSettingsToXmlFile(AppSetting appSetting)
    {
      var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AppSetting));
      var tw = new StreamWriter(GlobalConstants.XmlFile);
      xs.Serialize(tw, appSetting);
    }

    public static AppSetting GetAppSettingsFromXmlFile()
    {
      if (!File.Exists(GlobalConstants.XmlFile))
      {
        return new AppSetting();
      }

      using (var sr = new StreamReader(GlobalConstants.XmlFile))
      {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AppSetting));
        return (AppSetting)xs.Deserialize(sr);
      }
    }


  }
}
```

My save is working perfectly but it is not saving the values as encrypted strings.

I thought this would handle it on the fly but it's not doing anything:

```
public string DataSource
{
  set => _dataSource = Encryption.SimpleEncryptWithPassword(value, GlobalConstants.EncryptionPassword);
  get => Encryption.SimpleDecryptWithPassword(_dataSource, GlobalConstants.EncryptionPassword);
}
```

I am not getting any error messages, it's just not encrypting the data.

Any suggestions how I encrypt certain properties before they are saved?

**EDIT:** 
I'd prefer not to encrypt the entire file if I can prevent it. I would like to only encrypt the properties that I choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `XmlSerializer` serializes only **public** properties and fields -- and the public properties in your `AppSetting` class are all unencrypted.  From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/introducing-xml-serialization)

> XML serialization serializes only the public fields and property values of an object into an XML stream. ...
>
> XML serialization does not convert methods, indexers, private fields, or read-only properties (except read-only collections). To serialize all an object's fields and properties, both public and private, use the [DataContractSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer) instead of XML serialization.

Thus your options are:

1. Make public properties for the encrypted members and mark the plaintext properties with [`XmlIgnore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute?view=netframework-4.8) like so:

   ```
   [System.ComponentModel.Browsable(false), System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsable(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Never), System.Diagnostics.DebuggerBrowsable(System.Diagnostics.DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
   [XmlElement("DataSource")] // Optionally change the element name to be <DataSource>
   public string EncryptedDataSource { get; set; }

   [XmlIgnore]
   public string DataSource
   {
       set => EncryptedDataSource = Encryption.SimpleEncryptWithPassword(value, GlobalConstants.EncryptionPassword);
       get => Encryption.SimpleDecryptWithPassword(EncryptedDataSource, GlobalConstants.EncryptionPassword);
   }
   ```

   Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6i6AH8).
2. Switch to [`DataContractSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer?view=netframework-4.8).   First modify your class as follows:

   ```
   [DataContract]
   public class AppSetting
   {
       [DataMember(Name = "DataSource")]
       private string _dataSource;
       [DataMember(Name = "IntitialCatalog")]
       private string _intitialCatalog;
       [DataMember(Name = "UserId")]
       private string _userId;
       [DataMember(Name = "Password")]
       private string _password;

       // Remainder unchanged
   ```

   Then modify `XmlReader` as follows:

   ```
   public static void WriteAppSettingsToXmlFile(AppSetting appSetting)
   {
       var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(AppSetting));
       using (var stream = new FileStream(GlobalConstants.XmlFile, FileMode.Create))
       {
           serializer.WriteObject(stream, appSetting);
       }
   }

   public static AppSetting GetAppSettingsFromXmlFile()
   {
       if (!File.Exists(GlobalConstants.XmlFile))
       {
           return new AppSetting();
       }
       using (var stream = File.OpenRead(GlobalConstants.XmlFile))
       {
           var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(AppSetting));
           return (AppSetting)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
       }
   }
   ```

   The resulting properties will all be encrypted.

   Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XnPO1Q).

Notes:

- In `WriteAppSettingsToXmlFile()` you do not dispose the `StreamWriter`.  This will leave the file open and possibly lead to errors later.  Instead, do:

  ```
  public static void WriteAppSettingsToXmlFile(AppSetting appSetting)
  {
      var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AppSetting));
      using (var tw = new StreamWriter(GlobalConstants.XmlFile))
      {
          xs.Serialize(tw, appSetting);
      }
  }
  ```
- While properties serialized with `XmlSerializer` **must** be public, you can hide them a little by marking them with [`[Browsable(false)]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute?view=netframework-4.8), [`[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute?view=netframework-4.8) and [`[DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debuggerbrowsableattribute?view=netframework-4.8),

Comment: That's pretty fricking sweet! Awesome job tyvm!